# Remove a project from source control without removing the rest of the solution

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

VS 2019/2017

I have a solution which consists of the core projects and some test projects.

Using Visual Studio source control tools, I would like to upload to the remote repo only the core projects - is there a way i can remove the test projects from source control while still keeping them on my local solution?

Comment: Can't you just ignore the whole project in gitignore file?

Comment: @Matt That doesn't work, because the `.sln` breaks when you clone the code on another machine if a project is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this, because the `.sln` file, who that describe the solution, point to all projects in the solution. And if some project will not be under the source control, it will break the `.sln` file.

But there is some partial solutions:

1. Don't use an `.sln` file at all. If the root leaf of the dependencies tree is a single project, you can always compile this project, and it will compile its dependencies.
2. Manage two solutions. Two `.sln` files, one for all projects, include the tests, and one without them.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `.gitignore` file and list all files / folders into the file that we want to ignore while uploading the project into the remote repository.

Also, refer the following site to know more about it: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/79040f47-b634-447c-bc13-1161e572ca9e/how-to-remove-a-solution-from-tfs-source-control-without-deleting-the-local-copy-of-source-files?forum=tfsgeneral